# How can I code a class to receive a property for use with custom renderers?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have seen this coding style:

```
    public CustomTextCell()
    {
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
            "IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomTextCell),
        defaultValue: false);

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and this:

```
public class ExtViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public bool NoTap { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help explain the difference.  Is one serving a different function from the other? In my case all I need is to pass to a custom renderer the value of NoTap.  Should I code it like in the first or second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is a *POCO* - a *plain old C# object* - that is relatively self-explanatory, but serves not much more purpose that holding data - and not that much in this case.

The first one is a bit more interesting, especially in the context of MVVM. `SetValue` does more than just setting the value, but will (in most cases) raise `PropertyChanged` event (see [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)), to notify subscribers that, well, a property has changed.

**Now how does this relate to your custom renderer?** You *could* implement the property in your view as a *plain property* - i.e. without notifications - and it might work (cannot tell, though, since I do not know your custom renderer) when setting `IsChecked` initially (and without binding). Anyway, imagine you'll update the value of `IsChecked`. You do so from your code and wonder, why this change is not reflected in your custom renderer. **But how is your renderer supposed to know?** Polling each and every property might be possible for smaller forms, but is a terrible waste of resources. (*And* Xamarin.Forms just does not work this way.) You'll page/view has to tell your custom renderer, that something has changed. `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the rescue. In your custom renderer you can subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event and react to `IsChecked` being changed, updating your native view.